# RabbitMq java client: subscribe to queue with rate-limiting

Tags: java, scala, rabbitmq

I'm using [rabbitmqclient](https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html) for RabbitMQ (from Scala). I subscribe to a queue via `DefaultConsumer` and consume the messages from few instances concurrently.

The problem is that when the first consumer starts, it immediately takes all existing messages from the queue, so other nodes will consume only newer messages. I'd like to configure the consumers to take, say, not more than 10 messages at a time. It's definitely possible to rewrite it using pull-based API and manage back pressure manually, but I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: So you are using the push API? How much time does it take for the consumer to work on and acknowledge each message? How long does it take for the other consumers to start consuming from the queue? And why do you want to wait for them?

Comment: Message rate is low (~300 messages/day) and processing of each message is rather slow (1-40 minutes). It works fine most of the time but if I need to restart my cluster of consumers the first node takes all pending messages. Each node starts in ~3 seconds if it's important.

Comment: Maybe use a [consumer prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) of 1 on the consumer.

Comment: Thank you, looks like it's the solution.